# how to pass data using rest api of cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying as follows:

From Client:

```php
 $link = 'http://app.itexpertbd.com/' . 'rest_filters/index.json';

 $http = new Client();

 $data['Phone']['name'] = 'New Phone';
 $data['Phone']['manufacturer'] = 'New Phone Manufacturer';
 $data['Phone']['description'] = 'New Phone Description';
 $response = $http->get($link,$data);
```

And REST API end point:

```php
public function index() {
     $return = $data;
     $this->set(array(
         'return' => $return,
         '_serialize' => array('return')
     ));  
}
```

But when I inspect `$response->body`, it is empty. What is the problem in my approach?

Comment: Have you enabled [RESTful Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#restful-routing) as well as using the [RequestHandlerComponent](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html#request-handling) in your application? If not, it is possible that your view will not render as you expect.

Comment: Also you are using the `get` method instead of `post` to pass the data to your API end point.